# CWP | User login --> uerror -- Cannot login as a user in CentOS 8 using Centos Panel

Tags: centos, centos7, vps, centos8

I'm really feeling very frustrated...

2 days now and I couldn't figure it out.
Without a good reason, I had a "uerror" when trying to login into CWP user panel.
[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWm8h.jpg)

I'm pretty sure of the credentials, also, I've done the following:

1- Changed the user package.
2- Tried to update CWP.
3- Restarted all services.
4- Rebooted server.
5-Deleted and re-created the account.

here are some error logs:

```
=> /usr/local/cwp/php71/var/log/php-fpm.log <==
[23-Nov-2020 18:34:20] WARNING: [pool login] child 65870 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message:          PHP Notice:  Undefined index: intended in /usr/local/cwpsrv/var/services/users/login/index.php on line 0"
[23-Nov-2020 18:34:20] WARNING: [pool login] child 65870 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: intended in /usr/local/cwpsrv/var/services/users/login/index.php on line 0"
```

apache error log: https://pastebin.com/HEz5rN4F

cwp php-fpm log: https://pastebin.com/hcHbzUCj

php-fpm-slowlog-cwpsrv: https://pastebin.com/J87b10hV

php-fpm-slowlog-someuser: https://pastebin.com/Yyi53kNc

Any help would be greatly appreciated  :-*

Comment: Really don't know why this is downvoted!! if it is in the wrong stack site then there should be a request to move it!!!

Comment: Probably because panels are off-topic for Server Fault.

Comment: Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply. Some related topics may be asked on Webmasters or see Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem but it is very strange!!

After weeks of trying, I've reinstalled the operating system.
Then I configured my server and the user panel worked correctly.
BUT...
I did these steps and the error "uerror" reappeared!!
1- Changed my default MySQL password for root from PhpMyAdmin.
2- To reflect root password changes:

- I've changed root password in:

  /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/db_conn.php
- I've changed root password in:

  /root/.my.cnf

Then tried to enter CWP user panel and again got the annoying "uerror"!!!

To confirm that this was the error, I reverted back to the default root password in all steps above and the CWP user panel worked again without the "uerror" !!

Now what happened?!! and how to get rid of this? this has no answer yet!

Answer (score 0):

This is the error related to language selection in cwp, you can go to cwp filemanager and locate login page, go to the botom section and set default language direct in js like below and remove select language section

type: "POST",
url: "/login/index.php?acc=validate",
data:"username="+userN+"&password="+pass+"&sessioning="+sessioning+**"&userlang=en"**,

or just make a default language first in the select language section of loginform

**option value="en">{{langmod.LGLANGD}}**